# How do you get spray paint drips off wooden desk

Tags: wood, desk, spray-paint

I decided to spray paint my desk matte black and glossy red.
I spray painted the top and it was fine but I sprayed the sides and I got drips.
I woke up the next morning to find the drips dry and I don't know how to get them off.

Please help its my main pc desk.

Comment: Sand gently and respray.

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely have to shoot the spots with new paint. But first, scrape them off. Preferably a square edge of stiff plastic, the square edge is your scraper or hopefully popper...the plastic will do no or little damage to the area. If that doesn't do it then carefully scrape them flush & invisible with a razor blade. Then, just shoot these areas again to re-matte or re-gloss them. Sanding will affect a larger area & will result in absolutely having to re-paint most of the panel.